# See failed logons in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

I understand that you can see failed logons in Windows 10 - how can I do that?

Also, can you filter that by failed or successful logins? This is for Windows 10, Home Edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But first you have to enable it in your group policy.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `gpedit.msc` (folowed by pressing <kbd>return</kbd>)
2. Click through the following tree:

   > Computer Configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings →
   >   Local Policies → Audit Policy
3. On the right panel double-click **Audit logon events**
4. Mark **Success** and **Failure** (if you want both to be logged)
5. Confirm those settings by pressing the OK button

You can now find your Audit Failure and Success entries in your eventviewer:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `eventvwr` (followed by pressing <kbd>return</kbd>)
2. Open the **Windows Logs Tree** and click on **Security**

There you will find all entries.

You can also create a filter to only show your successful and failed logon attempts:

1. On the eventviewer click on **Filter Current Log...**
2. Change `<All event IDs>` to `4624,4625`

The eventID `4624` shows your successful attempts, thereas `4625` shows the failed ones.

**Remember:** you will only find those attempts being logged since you've changed the group policy! So you can't see it for the past.

Comment: Sorry, but he can't find gpedit.msc.

Comment: Ah you are using the home version... There is no group policy editor included. However you can install it. You can find a how to on the following page: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/

Even though it's saying that it's for Windows 7 it should be working on Windows 10 too.

Comment: Is Local Security Policy [`secpol.msc`] also not included in Home?  If it is, _Security Settings - Local Policies - Audit Policy_